# Entity Framework - Eagerly loading a virtual collection's related records

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

After migrating to EF6 I expected to be able to iterate through an entity's virtual collection of related records making use of eager loading to ensure best query efficiency as needed. However, when trying to use the `Include` eager loading function on the virtual collection, this doesn't work.

Since accessing these virtual collections results in lazy loading with DB queries, I assumed there would be some ability to control these queries.

Consider the following definitions:

```
class Group
{
    public virtual ICollection<Member> Members {get;set;}
}
class Member
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public virtual User User {get;set;}
}
class User
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

I need to query for all all the members of a group along with each associated User without lazily and inefficiently querying for each user separately. I tried using `Include` on a virtual `ICollection` which was allowed and retrieved the data but still used lazy loading instead of eager loading.

```
var members = group.Members.Include(m => m.User);
```

I can imagine that implementing these related entities using `ICollection` was probably done for good abstraction reasons. As such they may not seem like an obvious place to expose query functionality. But the fact is that using these virtual properties are intended to be the primary way to interact with a DB record's related objects. And since this results in queries a dev should be able to optimize them if needed.

`Include` is currently only functional on `IQueryable` objects. Calling `AsQueryable` on the `ICollection` also doesn't work. The only way to achieve what I need is to go the long way around by building a query from scratch.

```
using (var db = Context()) 
{
    var memberIds = group.Members.Select(m => m.ID);
    db.Members.Include(m => m.User).Where(m => memberIds.Includes(m.ID));
}
```

This performs 2 DB queries instead of 1 + N (number of members in the collection) for lazy loading. I can write my own single query to do the whole thing but I really want to be able to use the built-in collections and navigation properties to achieve this.

Does anyone know of a simpler way to use virtual props & collections while optimizing for eager loading? I suppose a custom extension on `ICollection` should make it possible to use this the way I want.

Comment: What is `group`? What is `Includes` in `memberIds.Includes(m.ID)`?

Comment: @GuruStron lmgtfy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data

Comment: There is no.mention of `Includes` method on this page.

Comment: Your code contains too many black boxes. What is `group`, to begin with? Where's the virtual collection? What *does* happen when you do `group.Members.Include(m => m.User)`? What is a virtual collection *shortcut*? What is this `memberIds.Includes` method? Please turn this into a [mre].

Comment: @GuruStron you ... didn't read it did you?
"NOTE: Include is an extension method in the System.Data.Entity namespace so make sure you are using that namespace."

Comment: @jpro _"i'm not here to teach you how EF6 does relations, eager loading and their Include function"_ - I have a slight suspicion that  Gert Arnold can teach you a thing or two about how relations work in EF =)

Comment: @jpro please rewrite the question because it's very hard to understand what you want. `Include` doesn't call or execute anything, it tells EF to include, ie eagerly load ,the related entities even if they aren't mentioned in the Select, *when the query executes*. Usually that means JOINing tables. It has no effect afterwards.  It doesn't care about virtual properties, those are needed for on-demand, ie lazy loading. You can  also [explicitly load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/explicit) related entities 
        .Collection(b => b.Posts)
        .Load();)

Comment: @jpro after reading Gert Arnold's answer, I suspect what you really wanted to ask is how to load the relations of the relations? If you have a Group, how to load both the Group.Members and Member.Users? That's what `ThenInclude` is for. AFAIK there's no nested explicit loading - no `ThenCollection`

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth discussion. I recognize it wasn't a clear question. I have taken a bunch more time to revise and clarify the question.

Comment: After I answered your question you added *But the fact is that using these virtual properties are intended to be the primary way to interact with a DB record's related objects.* -- That's your key premise. However, most EF developers won't second that. I'd contend that eager loading (i.e. `Inlcude`) is the primary way. Lazy loading is highly complicating and explicit loading is used rarely in my experience. Maybe for you the latter two are the primary way, but don't expect EF to focus much on these loading patterns.

Comment: @GertArnold, as far as i can tell using `Include` still requires 2 queries at a minimum: 1 to get a list of ids and the second to make the actual `Include` query using those ids. are you saying that this is the most efficient mechanism that the majority of EF devs use even though a custom query could reduce the number to a single query? Efficiency is my primary goal here but it feels like EF is not designed to make maximum efficiency very easy.

Comment: What I say is that of the three patterns for loading related data, `Include` is the most efficient and popular one. It typically does *not* take two queries, I don't know where that idea comes from. It *may* involve multiple queries but only when using `AsSplitQuery()`. Then, aside from these patterns, there is what you call "custom query", which is called *projection*. Everybody agrees that is by far the most efficient and recommended way to query data. But it has nothing to do with querying entire entities and their relationships, which is what your question is all about.

Comment: @GertArnold the idea of requiring multiple queries is from the example. i would have to query for a list of `Group`'s related `Member` ids and then query for the list of `Member` and joined `User` rows (using Include) in a second query. I cannot see a way to use EF in order to perform the single query that is possible to write manually. this conclusion leaves me to believe that EF is not designed for efficiency.

Comment: What I don't understand is, why don't you get the `Group` with an `Include` query? `context.Groups.Include(g => g.Members).FirstOrDefault(g => g.Id  == idValue)`? You seem to know the (existing) `Include` method.

Answer (score 0):

> there is no way to use an entity's virtual collection along with the Include function

It took some discussion before it was clear what you meant by this.

Given that in...

```cs
group.Members.Include(m => m.User);
```

...`group` is a `Group` object that was previously pulled from the database with its `Members` eagerly loaded by `Include`, you expected that the statement above could be used to load each of the members' `User` property.

Sure, that would be great, but...

- In [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#eager-loading) it says

  > You can use the `Include` method to specify related data to be included in query results.

  Maybe it doesn't stand out enough, but "in query results" means that `Include` works in *queries*, i.e. `IQueryable`s. You found that out because the statement above doesn't compile. It compiles when using `group.Members.AsQueryable`, but then `Include` does nothing, because `AsQueryable` creates an object that doesn't have an `Include` implementation. It takes too much to explain all of that, but suffice to say that `group` is just a plain C# object that doen't have any knowledge of what it was created by. It has no contact with EF's query provider that could generate a query for loading nested objects and `AsQueryable` doesn't "inject" this query provider. (Even then it would be hard to do it efficiently).
- Suppose it could. Then it wouldn't depend on properties being `virtual` or not. Just as the regular `Inlude` method loads virtual and non-virtual properties.
- It wouldn't work as you expect. You seem to desire that `group.Members.Include(m => m.User)` loads all `User` objects on the spot. But EF's `Include` method doesn't *execute* eager loading, it only *specifies* it. It amends an `IQueryable` by instructions to eager load nested data. But an `IQueryable` in itself does nothing, it only returns data when it's forced to execute (which is referred to as *deferred execution*).

So either you should `Include` User from the outset, by something like...

```cs
db.Groups.Include(g => g.Members).ThenInclude(m => m.User)
```

...or let lazy loading do its job, but as you said, that's inefficient because it runs one query per `User` object.

#### In conclusion

Yes, it would be great to have functionality that could efficiently expand an object graph one level deeper. I just don't see how EF could implement that easily, or at all.

Comment: Perhaps the OP is looking for explicit loading? Even given this answer I can't understand what the question is

Comment: I don't think they are. It took some pondering before getting it, which I think I do now. Explicit loading is, in fact, the same as lazy loading but then executed, well, explicitly. The point is (I think), `Include` can't be applied after the fact. It must be part of the original query. After that, no chance.

Comment: Perhaps a `Collection(g=>g.Members).ThenCollection(m=>m.Users)`? That doesn't exist and would require a three-way JOIN anyway. The effect/cost would be almost the same as reloading the `Group` with `Include().ThenInclude()`, unless `Group` is very wide. That's swimming in the leaky abstaction's .... reservoir

Comment: Yeah, surely there's a lot more to this than what I answered. Like, I ignored the fact that `group` can be a proxy and that *maybe* EF could use its lazy loader somehow. Maybe at this point it's not even swimming. Floating. Drifting?

Comment: @GertArnold i think you understand now. in my opinion, since calling `group.Members.ToList()` executes a query and an `ICollection` behaves in many of the same ways to `IQueryable` i expected to be able to control the resulting query. any idea why they didn't use `DbSet` to represent the related records?

Comment: Using `DbSet` would require all entities to have a dependency on EF, erasing all advantages of working with POCOs. Lazy loading *sort of* adds DbSet capabilties to a navigation properties by overriding them (note, BTW, that `User` can't be a `DbSet`), but you can't add filtering. If you want that, you can use filtered `Include` or explicit loading with filters. Also keep in mind that lazy loading is by no means the standard. IMO it's almost an anti-pattern because it makes software far more complex and unpredictable.

Answer (score -1):

When you have two model and there is a relation between models. like that:

```cs
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Member 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

If you load member without include the member.User is null

If you use include the user with this condition `User.Id == Member.UserId` load and set in member.User

```cs
var member = dbContext.Members.Include(m => m.User).First();
```

EF generate sql query when you use include like that:

```sql
select top 1 m.*, u.*
from Members m
join users u on u.Id = m.UserId
```